# Combining jquery functions and methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Pretty new to jquery so this could be a "really man" type of question.  But say I have two functions that I want to combine into one but there are slight differences, for example the next() and the prev() methods and the first and last pseudo-selectors are different in each function:

```
function rotateImage(){

var currentPhoto = $("#photo_slideshow .current");  
var nextPhoto = currentPhoto.next();

if(nextPhoto.length == 0){
nextPhoto = $("#photo_slideshow div:first");
}

}

function rotateImage2(){

var currentPhoto = $("#photo_slideshow .current");  
var nextPhoto = currentPhoto.prev();

if(nextPhoto.length == 0){
nextPhoto = $("#photo_slideshow div:last");
}
}
```

There's got to be a way to combine the two functions to condense the code.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could provide a boolean as argument. But all of this depends on the way the functions are called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide some argument inside function.something that'll determine whether next is called or previous is called.do something like this.

```
function rotateImage(side){

var currentPhoto = $("#photo_slideshow .current");  
if(side=="next"){
var nextPhoto = currentPhoto.next();
if(nextPhoto.length == 0){
nextPhoto = $("#photo_slideshow div:first");
}
if(side=="prev")
{
var nextPhoto = currentPhoto.prev();
if(nextPhoto.length == 0){
nextPhoto = $("#photo_slideshow div:last");
}
}
```

While calling:
for next use `rotateImage("next")` for previous use `rotateImage("prev")`

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```
function rotateImage(which, pseudoSelector) {

    var currentPhoto = $("#photo_slideshow .current");  
    var nextPhoto = currentPhoto[which]();

    if(nextPhoto.length == 0){
        nextPhoto = $("#photo_slideshow div:" + pseudoSelector);
    }

}


rotateImage('next', 'first');
rotateImage('prev', 'last');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function rotateImage(side){
var isNext = side == 'next';

var currentPhoto = $("#photo_slideshow .current");  
var nextPhoto = isNext ? currentPhoto.next() : currentPhoto.prev();

if(nextPhoto.length == 0){
nextPhoto = $("#photo_slideshow " + (isNext ? "div:first" : "div:last"));
}}
```

- Use rotateImage('next') **to rotate next.**
- Use rotatImage() or rotateImage('prev') or rotateImage() **to rotate to previous.**